# Why do people use sqrt(dot(distanceVector, distanceVector)) over OpenGL's distance function?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, webgl

When using ShaderToy I often see people using something like:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution;
vec2 centerPoint = vec2(0.5);

vec2 distanceVector = uv - centerPoint;
float dist = sqrt(dot(distanceVector, distanceVector));
```

over OpenGL's `distance` function:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution;
vec2 centerPoint = vec2(0.5);

float dist = distance(uv, centerPoint);
```

I'm just curious why this is (my guess is that it has something to do with speed or support for `distance`).

I loosely understand that if the arguments are the same, the square root of a dot product equals the length of the vector: the distance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing essentially the same thing, people often choose the sqrt option for one of two reasons:
1. They don't know about/remember the distance function
2. They are trusting themselves and their own math to prove that is not a problem to cause a bug (avoiding OpenGL problems)

Comment: Is it faster? or can you compare two function cycles?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes to optimize early exits as for light volumes for example:

```
float distSquared( vec3 A, vec3 B )
{

    vec3 C = A - B;
    return dot( C, C );

}

// Early escape when the distance between the fragment and the light 
// is smaller than the light volume/sphere threshold.
//float dist = length(lights[i].Position - FragPos);
//if(dist < lights[i].Radius)
// Let's optimize by skipping the expensive square root calculation
// for when it's necessary.
float dist = distSquared( lights[i].Position, FragPos );
if( dist < lights[i].Radius * lights[i].Radius )
{ 
 
    // Do expensive calculations.
```

If you need the `distance` later on simply:

```
dist = sqrt( dist )
```

EDIT: Another example.

Another use case that I've recently learnt, suppose that you want to have two positions: `vec3 posOne` and `vec3 posTwo` and you want the distance to each of those. The naive way would be to compute them independently: `float distanceOne = distance( posOne, otherPos )` and `float distanceTwo = distance( posTwo, otherPos )`. But you want to exploit SIMD! So you do: `posOne -= otherPos; posTwo -= otherPos` so you are ready to compute the euclidean distance by SIMD: `vec2 SIMDDistance = vec2( dot( posOne ), dot( posTwo ) );` and you can then use SIMD for the square root: `SIMDDistance = sqrt( SIMDDistance );` where the distance to posOne is on the .x component of the SIMDDistance variable and the .y component contains the distance to posTwo.

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Book of Shader](https://thebookofshaders.com/07/), `distance()` and `length()` use `sqrt()` internally. Using `sqrt()` and all the functions depend on it can be expensive. Just use `dot()` if possible!

I guess `sqrt()` is a **mathematical computation**, but `dot()` is a **vector computation** which GPU is good at.

Comment: This is true, but the question was about `sqrt(dot(...))` vs `distance(...)`. In the scenarios they mention, the `sqrt` is not being avoided. So this isn't really an answer to the question, and more is a sort of tangential comment. I might be more inclined to consider it an answer to the question if you have some suggestions of specific scenarios where you could switch from `distance` and avoid the sqrt. One that comes to mind is if you know the maximum distance that might be involved, and are looking for a ratio, and are OK with a non-linear result. Or if doing a < or > check.

Comment: just say something detail of the question, lol. `distance(...)` is really more semantic

Answer (score 1):

Using dot gives you a quick way to experiment with quadratic/linear function of distance.

Answer (score 1):

What I often do is the following (example):

```
vec3 vToLight = light.pos - cam.pos;
float lengthSqToLight = dot(vToLight, vToLight);
if (lengthSqToLight > 0 && lengthSqToLight <= maxLengthSq) {
    float lengthToLight = sqrt(lengthSqToLight); // length is often needed later
    ...
    vec3 vToLightNormalized = vToLight / lengthToLight; // avoid normalize() => avoids second sqrt
    ...
    // later use lengthToLight
}
```